# Convert Date from SQLite and populate a Listview

Tags: android, sqlite, listview, date, time

i'm having a problem where I have a field with a datetime value and want to display a formatted value on a listview.
Can someone please take a look at my code and help with this one?

```java
cursor = db.getAllSms();
startManagingCursor(cursor);
int mTime= cursor.getColumnIndex(DBAdapter.KEY_DATETIME);



    String[] from = new String[cursor.getCount()];
    int[] to = new int[] {R.id.label};
    int counter = 0;
    for (cursor.moveToFirst(); !cursor.isAfterLast(); cursor.moveToNext()){
        SimpleDateFormat sdf = new SimpleDateFormat("dd MMMM yyyy HH:mm");

        Date resultdate = new Date(cursor.getLong(mTime));
        String mDateTime = sdf.format(resultdate);
        from[counter] = mDateTime;
        counter++;
    }



    SimpleCursorAdapter users = new SimpleCursorAdapter(this, R.layout.sms_row, cursor, from, to);
    setListAdapter(users);
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

SimpleCursorAdapter is too simple for what you're trying to do.  The 'from' parameter is actually an array of column names, and the data will be mapped directly from the cursor to a corresponding TextView for each row in the cursor.

I've been told that a correct way would be to extend TextView to understand the data as it is stored in your cursor and internally handle the formatting.  But, another, maybe less technically correct way is as follows:

Extend CursorAdapter and put the logic above into bindView.  For example:

```java
class DateTimeCursorAdapter extends CursorAdapter {
    LayoutInflater mInflater;

    private int mTime;
    SimpleDateFormat sdf; 

    DateTimeCursorAdapter(Context context, Cursor cursor)
    {
        super(context, cursor);
        mInflater = (LayoutInflater) context
                .getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);

        mTime = cursor.getColumnIndex(DBAdapter.KEY_DATETIME);
        sdf = new SimpleDateFormat("dd MMMM yyyy HH:mm");

    }

    public View newView(Context context, Cursor cursor, ViewGroup parent)
    {
        return mInflater.inflate(R.layout.dispatchesrow, parent, false);
    }

    public void bindView(View row, Context context, Cursor cursor)
    {
        TextView tvLabel = (TextView) row
                .findViewById(R.id.label);


        Date resultdate = new Date(cursor.getLong(mTime));
        String mDateTime = sdf.format(resultdate);
        tvLabel.setText(mDateTime);         
    }

}
```

Then:

```java
Cursor c = mDB.getSms();
startManagingCursor(c);
DateTimeCursorAdapter adapter = new DateTimeCursorAdapter(this, cursor);
setListAdapter(adapter);
```

Comment: I am a little bit late, but your answer is great! It works great and thank you! I only have to add 2 things: In the newView() the layout inflated is the item layout of the listview and secondly, the startManagingCursor method is deprecated and need to be handled carefully.